# Why Windows 10 won't wake up from prolonged sleep (or hibernate or shutdown) conditions?

Tags: windows-10, bsod, sleep, shutdown, hibernate

I have a ThinkPad T420 running Windows 10 with this characteristics:

- CPU: Core i5 2520m
- RAM: 16 GB Crucial
- Graphics: Intel HD and NVIDIA NVS 4200
- Storages:

  1. SAMSUNG SSD EVO 850 (as OS disk in a bracket inserted instead of DVD
     ROM)
  2. WD HDD 320GB 7200 rpm

I have worked for several mounts with this system perfectly and there was no problem. Newly, a bad problem has been appeared: when I put the system to sleep for a long time, the system won't wake up (the power LED flashing, Bluetooth LED and CPU fan being on). After force shutdown, in the boot process BSD error occurs and after several restart, finally Windows will boot.
The BSD occurs when I turn on the laptop after a prolonged shutdown or hibernate also. I emphasize that the problem occurs when sleep conditions (or being turned off or hibernated) is for a long time (more than an hour) and in short time periods, there is no error!!!! The computer restart command works properly (shutting down via the Windows and booting again).
I tried several solutions from internet search as followed without permanent success:

1. Check disk (with /f and /r flags)
2. sfc /scannow
3. Power management modifications (disabling hybrid sleep, disabling HDD turn off, disabling hibernation, disabling wake up timer)
4. Fresh installing Windows (Windows 7 and 10) several times
5. Updating bios to the latest version
6. Updating windows to the latest released updates
7. Updating drivers to the latest versions
8. Disabling intel SpeedStep technology from within bios settings (it worked for some days, but the problem came back!)
9. Disabling NVIDIA from bios and working with intel graphics only and vice versa.
10. Fully cleaning SSD with clean command from "diskpart" and with SAMSUNG secure erase tool in SAMSUN magician.
11. Removing the HDD from laptop.
12. Changing the SSD port (in DVD ROM port and in default HDD port)
13. Reputing RAMs and exchanging their slot positions.
14. Full hardware checks not showing any problem in the hardware (memory, HDD, SSD, Motherboard and …)
15. Removing battery and AC power separately.
16. Testing three conditions in the virtual memory settings: automatic page file, customized page file and no page file.

The other things maybe important to noticed is that the problem began after a fully battery discharge when the laptop was in sleep mode. The BSDs are different but the most frequent one is "Kernel security check failed". Sometimes it is "memory management" with no logged information in dump files (logging is enable in the windows setting).

A major question: basically, what is the difference between prolonged sleep (or shutdown) and short time ones?!

I read in an internet page about a problem similar to the current that the final solution is migration to Linux OS! is it true?

Please help me to resolve this problem. I have sent this question to Lenovo forum and Microsoft Answer but I didn't received any reply or answer!

Answer (score 0):

So you've exhausted all the options. You're down to hunting bugs and error logs and what not. This is a bad situation to be in.

I'd ask myself if I really need hibernation. My solution to the situation would be to live with it by just using total shutdown (you have an SSD, booting should be pretty fast anyway). Or totally reinstall Windows and see if that helps. This would be the logical conclusion (when all else fails).

In cases like this maybe a very experienced IT guy might be able to help you out by spending hours on your machine. If you're not that guy and can't find one, just do other things that will improve your situation.

This would be a smaller pain than switching to Linux just for keeping hibernation. The Linux thing might actually work, but you'll have to do tons of stuff differently. Is hibernation really worth it?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem isn't only for sleep or hibernation (as I mentioned), but also for total shutdown ("shutdown -s -t 00" from command prompt) exists if it is prolonged! The big question in my mind is: what is the difference between prolonged sleep (or shutdown) and short time ones?!

Answer (score -1):

As per your update you have done most of any IT tech would suggest i noted you said "the problem began after a fully battery discharge " have you tried to test with another battery to remove the battery as an issue. Borrow a battery if possible that is of the same model. Also is the machine still under warranty you could try returning it but as you have already opened it and reset the RAM may be you cannot.